# How to connect Mysql with php mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Here Is my code:

```
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
$db=mysqli_select_db("root");`
```

And I got the following error:

> Warning The `mysqli->connect_error` property only works properly as of
>   PHP versions 5.2.9 and 5.3.0. Use the `mysqli_connect_error()` function
>   if compatibility with earlier PHP versions is required.

Comment: Please provide the error?

Comment: Warning
The mysqli->connect_error property only works properly as of PHP versions 5.2.9 and 5.3.0. Use the mysqli_connect_error() function if compatibility with earlier PHP versions is required.

Comment: You don't show your full code, probably you use `$conn->connect_error` to show database connection error, that why PHP show the warning.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Its Not right  Method You Using The Correct Methode is

```
<?php 
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","hack");
?>
```

You can find all the information about your problem here 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

Comment: Providing a URL to php docs and saying "You can find the solution to your problem here" is not a helpful answer.